# Deferrable content xaml

Tags: c#, xaml

This code prompt an XamlParseException :

> *'Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent'
>   threw an exception.' Line number '15' and line position '14'*.

```
<UserControl  x:Class="MyView.MainWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:bv="clr-namespace:MyModel.FaultLibrary;assembly=Controller"
         xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"       
         xmlns:i18n="http://wpflocalizeextension.codeplex.com"
         i18n:LocalizeDictionary.DesignCulture="en"
         i18n:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultAssembly="MyView"
         i18n:ResxLocalizationProvider.DefaultDictionary="I18n"
         xmlns:gif="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="448" d:DesignWidth="955" FontFamily="Arial"
         TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"
         SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
         UseLayoutRounding="True">
```

The innerException :

> Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: 'DataTemplateKey(MyModel.FaultLibrary.TestPoint)'  Key being added: 'DataTemplateKey(MyModel.FaultLibrary.TestPoint)'

I don't know why...

Thanks for help.

Comment: See http://blog.saraf.me/2011/02/set-property-threw-exception.html

Comment: and the **InnerException**?

Comment: I have already try to rebuild my solution, but it doesn't work for me, and I don't find any duplication.

Comment: did you find any solution? I am facing the same issue but not able to resolve it by any means.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some style/template which seems to be having the same key or else, some element is having multiple styles set. Check your resources and Resource Libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If a style is meant to be global (no x:Key set) it's TargetType will be used as the key to look it up. If you have multiple Styles with the same TargetType and different keys you need to set the x:Key-Attribute before you set the TargetType.
Example - change this:

```
<Style TargetType="Control" x:Key="MyStyle" />
```

to this:

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="Control" />
```

So all the Styles can be added with unique keys to the Ressource-Dictionary.